# Sejda pdftojpeg very slow

Tags: shell, pdf, sejda

I have a service that acts as a pdf viewer by calling sejda and displaying the images sejda converts to jpeg using the console command:

```
 ./bin/sejda-console pdftojpeg --files /tmp/myfile.pdf -o /tmp/ -j overwrite
```

It seems to take around 20 to 30 seconds to generate the image, is there anything I can do speed up the process or optimize java (already set the memory to 20148m

Comment: The performance of this task depends on a number of things. Among them the number of pages and how complex it is to render them (thinking AutoCAD drawings for example). Can you share a sample file?

One way that we've used to speed things up when the number of pages in the doc was causing the task to take a long time was to batch it into several parts: first 10 pages, next 10 pages, etc. Page ranges are available in the java API but looking at the console options I think they aren't yet available in the console. Do you think this approach would help you?

Comment: I had line breaks in my comment that made it more readable but they seem to be removed, sorry.

Comment: Other options to explore: this Sejda task uses the IcePDF library, which has some properties that can be tweaked: http://www.icesoft.org/wiki/display/PDF/System+Properties. Maybe interesting for you would be to check the effect of changing "org.icepdf.core.target.render" to VALUE_RENDER_SPEED

Comment: How would I change
org.icepdf.core.target.render    in the console version?

Comment: Through the JAVA_OPTS env variable. export JAVA_OPTS='-Dorg.icepdf.core.target.render=VALUE_RENDER_SPEED'

Comment: That didn't seem to change anything :/

Comment: Can we see a sample PDF file? How many pages does it contain?

Comment: My sample file was generated by the same scanner but is only 3 pages versus the 15 pages of the one I was testing before (can't share that one due to IP issues) This 3 page document finishes in about 2-3 seconds which seems odd.

Comment: http://jbarton.virtualkingdoms.net/SampleScan.pdf